# Complex object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript.I want to create a class that defines an object with this structure:

```
name(string),
Array{
       "nom-colonne":
                     {
                      "type":"value",
                       "filter":"value"
                     }
     }
```

Comment: have you tried something? typescript is just like javascript, objects are the same for both I believed

Comment: I tried to create class with name: string, and Array<{"nom-colonne":{"type":"value","filter":"value"}}> but i didn't know how to declare it.

Comment: are you sure a class is what you want to create, and not an interface?

Comment: yes because i want to have setters and getters not read only attributes

Comment: @toskv Why an interface over class?

Comment: @M98 An interface can be used to describe a structure. A class also encapsulates some methods that do some logic with that data. So if all you need is to define the type of a structure it's better to just use an interface. If you need some logic attached to an instance you should make a class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you might be looking for is an interface.

```
interface IExample {
    name: string;
    array: Array<{
        nomColonne: {
            type: string,
            typeWithSpecificValues: "value", | "key" // Alternative for type
            filter: string,
        }
    }>,
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
let example: IExample = {
    name: "Arnold",
    array: [
        nomColonne: {
            type: "value",
            typeWithSpecificValues: "key", // Alternative for type
            filter: "value",
        },
    ],
};
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: private _name:string;
   private _filterModel:Array<{ [s: string]: {type:string,filter:string} }>  i made this structure thank's for ur help also

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using interface?

Comment: no i used this structure but in a class cause i need setters and getters and other methods also ;)

Comment: @jjijji well, you didn't specify you needed methods or properties so I thought you might have been better off using an interface because I couldn't know better that the description you gave.